# How to access facebook public newsfeed json/xml without authentication

Tags: android, facebook

I was working with twitter APIs and I am able to get specific user's timeline (tweets) without making the end user to login.

How can I do this in facebook? I don't want my user to login to facebook. I just need some feeds from users/pages which are publicly shared.

Does facebook allows this? How to do it? Any links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Android but For Facebook API, I managed to get users / pages feed (public only) using the graph for a small project I was working on, this snippet might
help you

```
<?php

$pageContent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts?fields=id,name&limit=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN HERE'); 
 // You can use your app token

  $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent); // decode JSON

  echo $id = $parsedJson->data[0]->id; // this echos only the latest post ID 
?>
```

So as you see, the code above requests Facebook graph and returns only post (latest one) from the user feed (because I limited it `&limit=1`) that code is working for me and might works for your needs

Comment: Cool. So the ACCESS_TOKEN is enough for that? I don't want to make my user to login

Comment: No, it **doesn't require user login**, but it **returns only public user's posts**, anyway I for that I have modified my graph URL so it returns only one post and id only so remove `fields=id,name` if you want to